# Validate Email Suffix Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I have a mailchimp subscription form, I am trying to validate the input value so it only accepts a specific type of email, `@gmail.com` for example.

`[name]@gmail.com`, if the user insert other than @gmail.com form should not be submitted, I tried to achieve this using regex but did not work, so how can I achieve such a function in JS.

Comment: Please share the code you tried as a [mcve] and explain what didn't work the way it should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doing what you want: `/@gmail\.com$/`

```js
var test = [
    'abc@gmail.com',
    'abc@not_gmail.com',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/@gmail\.com$/.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, anyway I used input mask to achieve what I want as I find it easier

Answer (score 1):

You can split and check part after @

```js
var test = [
    'abc@gmail.com',
    'abc@not_gmail.com',
]

test.forEach(i => {
  console.log(i.split('@')[1] === 'gmail.com')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [Toto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140003/6438359), but I would also like to check that the email prefix is correct using the regex from [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/6438359)

```js
var test = [
    'abc@gmail.com',
    'abc@not_gmail.com',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ': ' + /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@gmail\.com$/.test(a);
}));
```